# Using template tags in if statements in django

Tags: django, if-statement, django-templates

I am trying to check if the url returned by a template tag is the same as the one given.

```
{% ifequal  gravatar_for_email  project.creator.email  'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e/?default=&s=80' %}
```

I am currently getting the error message that ifequal takes two arguments.

So I tried to make a variable to use in the if
    {% gravatar_for_email  project.creator.email as var1 %}

But got the message
'gravatar_for_email' received too many positional arguments

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, you should be passing the result of the call directly in the context. Else, you can try this [template tag snippet](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/545/). Once added the following should work:

```
{% captureas creator_gravatar %}{% gravatar_for_email project.creator.email %}{% endcaptureas %}
{% ifequal creator_gravatar 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e/?default=&s=80' %}
```

Comment: I assume you meant ifequal creator_gravatar. Is there a way to dereference this variable afterwards? Otherwise creators without email addresses will get the same picture it seems

Comment: Corrected it. Yes, that's the idea. It becomes a variable in the context.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```
{% gravatar_for_email  project.creator.email|ifequal   'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e/?default=&s=80' %}
```

Comment: Note there's no whitespace between pipe sign.

Comment: invalid filter ifequal